# Is it possible to create an extension method that is called when the object is created?

Tags: c#

I cannot modify the object I am working with and I need a method but I really want it to be called when the object is created. So I was thinking that a extension method would be good here, however I don't know if it is possible but, if it is, then how?

EDITED:

My static class has this main object which I am supposed to create:

```
EcuVersion Ecu;
```

I will call this method from my class:

```
Ecu = ConvertAutodetect.Convert(rawData, Ecu, response);
```

and the platform will be looking for the Ecu object.

My method will return an EcuVersion object. This object contains a collection besides a lot of other things and I am working only with the respective collection which is:

```
ICollection<AutodetectStep> AutodetectSteps { get; set; }
```

AutodetectStep class has 4 childs and on one of it's childs I needed this extension method to be called when the child is created.

I have to create many childs and add them to the collection, also, I will never be instantiated my object because everything is static in there.

So is it suitable to use the factory pattern ?

Comment: What you mean by _want it to be called when the object is created_?

Comment: Because I am not supposed  to add any code there..

Comment: Maybe use a Factory?

Comment: Also, why can't you modify the constructor? It seems like that would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Create class which derive from your "not supposed to change" and add behaviour you want to the constructor of derived class

Comment: This is an object that was designed by others (its a platform with a lot of things) and I don't have rights to modify that code..

Comment: that's a tough problem.  they need to add a hook for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If it was it would be very unreliable because it would depend on whether you included relevant extension with `using` or not. That's actually general problem of extension methods but here it's even worse as it would never cause compile time error.

The best way how to implement this is probably using the factory pattern to indirectly construct the object and inject that factory in the code. This still doesn't solve the problem of existing code though.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class which inherit from your type

```
public class YourObject
{
    public YourObject()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {}
}

public class YourObjectWithExtraLogic : YourObject
{
    public YourObjectWithExtraLogic() : base()
    {
        // here add some extra logic
    }
}
```

Then you can use your class with extra logic anywhere where base class used.

```
public void Execute(YourObject obj)
{
    obj.SomeMethod();
}

var newObject = new YourObjectWithExtraLogic();
Execute(newObject);
```

With this approach you need to be careful not to violate "Liskov Substitution Principle".
For example your extra logic can not break expected behavior of base class.

Comment: Thats great Fabio, I was thinking at this solution but I really don't want to inherit all the things from that object because it has a lot of stuff that my object don't need

Comment: It is odd, you said you want only add some extra logic when object created(to the constructor). I think if you show some code examples of your class you can get more answers

Comment: @ChiritescuAdrian it might help to read again what Fabio is suggesting. especially the upvoted comment under your question because it seems you two are talking past each other. one key question to be answered is: how is the object that you cannot change created? (ie obtained from a factory or simply by invoking = new Object

Comment: Yes, it is simply created by invoking = new Object(), the thing is that factory may be used but I think it is not a good practice to inherit all from that object because I need all the things to be encapsulated in an object inside my object, the platform I am working on will be looking for it. Am I wrong regarding inheritance ?

Comment: @ChiritescuAdrian, sorry, can you provide some examples? What you mean by _all the things to be encapsulated in an object inside my object_ ?

Comment: @Fabio I just edited my question, hope you'll understand what is there, by the way, I resolved this problem in some other way, now is just for curiosity, thank you for your time.